# Migrating a database to the Cloud

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

I have a PC application (FoxPro) that uses a local database. I want to migrate it to a cloud database, but keeping the application intact.
Can I configure an ODBC Data Source in Windows XP/7 to point to a cloud database service such as SQL Azure, xeround.com, database.com or other?
Any experiences you'd like to share?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I discuss moving a client server application to cloud I always discuss moving the whole application + DB in cloud. If you move either one (application or database) to cloud and even when your application is geographically very close, you are still going to hit network latency as well as you would need to fiddle with your on-premise firewall settings to let other application get into. In most cases a client/server application needs be to converted to have a web front end to be cloud ready and there where I think the following article helps to understand the big picture:
http://www.visualwebgui.com/Technology/WhitePapers/tabid/528/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/919/Transformation-of-ClientServer-application-to-Windows-Azure-Cloud.aspx

About answer your question directly, if you want to use SQL Azure it is always good to understand the Limitation to move your DB to Cloud, because not every functionality in loca database is provided in most cloud databases:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx

Also be sure to know what you are going to get with your SQL Azure database:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621784.aspx

Finally you sure can use ODBC database connector to talk with SQL azure and if you are using ODBC then you would need to use .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC as described below:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sql-azure/#using-ODBC

Hope this helps to you and any other who is looking to migrate their client/server application to cloud. BTW this is a great question, +1 from me.

Comment: I have no experience using xeround cloud database so I dont know if it provides ODBC or any DB connectivity mechanism required by your application. However if you have your application running on-premise and your database is in Cloud, no matter which cloud DB you will choose, you will hit network latency. Choosing between SQL Azure and xeround, you sure can choose any one depend on application requirement and they both will work.

Answer (score 2):

ODBC data sources are supported by SQL Azure, but it would be best to use the SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC driver. The **General Guidelines and Limitations (SQL Azure Database)** article on MSDN contains more information about the ODBC support under the Tools and Technology Support heading.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible, but when I connected a local web app to a remote SQL Azure database, it became terribly slow. Not sure if Amarundo will have the same problem, but it's something to consider.

Comment: This could be a problem but it depends on external factors (like the connectivity of machine hosting the local app). Network connectivity should be an important consideration when moving to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Avakash that we should move the whole application + DB to the cloud unless there is some statutory or security need of hosting DB on premise.

I am working with Cloud since a few years and I found that there are a few virtualization services such as Ravello which provides option to move existing infra to Ravello cloud which runs on top of Google / Amazon.

The advantage I found was Ravello allow to migrate complere VM from your DC to cloud without making any changes to network or other configuration. Ravello provides nested virtualization as a service to make this easy. This means your vmdk will be running on top of EC2 as-is keeping your VMware tools, OS patch levels etc intact. 
This way you can move your DB, app everything to cloud very easily.

You can refer for this use case at http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/esxi-vm-to-ec2-vmware-tools/